# Constant rejection region for correlated multivariate normal observations

Tags: probability-theory

**STATEMENT OF PROBLEM:**

Suppose $ \left( \begin{array}{ccc} \ Z_1 \\ Z_2  \end{array} \right)$ follows a bivariate standard normal with covariance $ \rho $

$$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc} \ Z_1 \\ Z_2  \end{array} \right) \sim MVN  \left( \left( \begin{array}{ccc} \ 0 \\ 0  \end{array} \right) ,\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \rho  \\
\rho & 1  \\ \end{array} \right) \right) $$

I am trying to solve for the rejection region **c** *as a function of* $\alpha$ such that:

$$ P(|Z_1|\ge c) + P(|Z_1|<c , |Z_2| \ge c  ) =\alpha $$

**MY PAST ATTEMPTS:**

The solutions is easy when $\rho=0$, as
$$ P(|Z_1|\ge c) + P(|Z_1|<c , |Z_2| \ge c  ) =\alpha $$
by symmetry of LEFT probability, and by independence of that on the right...
$$ =2 [1-\Phi(c)] + P(|Z_1|<c) P(|Z_2| \ge c  ) =\alpha $$
$$ =2 [1-\Phi(c)] + 2 [1-\Phi(c)][\Phi(c)-\Phi(-c)] =\alpha $$
$$ 2 [1-\Phi(c)] + 2 [1-\Phi(c)][2 \Phi(c)-1] =\alpha $$
$$ 4 [1-\Phi(c)] \Phi(c)=\alpha $$
$$ 4 [\Phi(c)-\Phi(c)^2]=\alpha $$
$$ -4\Phi(c)^2+4\Phi(c)-\alpha=0 $$
which is a quadratic function of $\Phi(c)$, yielding
$$ \Phi(c)= \frac{1+\sqrt{1-\alpha}}{2} $$
Giving the solution for c as a function of $\alpha$:
$$ \boxed{c = \Phi^{-1} \left( \frac{1+\sqrt{1-\alpha}}{2} \right)} $$

However, when $\rho \ne0$, I cannot find a closed form solution!  All i can find is 
$$ 2 [1-\Phi(c)]+ 2 \int_{-c}^{c} \Phi\left( \frac{-c+\rho z}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\right)\phi(z) \, dz =\alpha $$
and solve it numerically.  **This WORKS, but does not yield the desired closed form solution**

The one hint that I was given was to use $ U_1 =Z_1 + Z_2$  and $U_2 = Z_1 - Z_2 $.  I tried this, to no avail.  Can anyone help??  Would normalizing $U_1$ and $U_2$ then squaring them be of any help??

**NOTE**

This problem goes on to ask for a similar solution when

$$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc} \ Z_1 \\ Z_2 \\Z_3  \end{array} \right) \sim MVN  \left( \left( \begin{array}{ccc} \ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0  \end{array} \right) ,\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \rho & \rho \\
\rho & 1 & \rho \\
\rho & \rho & 1 \end{array} \right) \right) $$

Solve for the rejection region **c** *as a function of* $\alpha$ such that:

$ P(|Z_1|\ge c) + P(|Z_1|<c , |Z_2| \ge c  )+ P(|Z_1|<c , |Z_2|<c , |Z_3| \ge c  ) =\alpha $

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/127258/6633) on stats.SE where there is even a 100-point bounty being offered for a solution.